# Accessing Production (Store App) Windows Phone local folder from PC

Tags: windows-phone, local-storage, development-environment, production

Is there a way to access store application local folder, assuming that this application is developed by me and I have the store key?

I have some bug that only happens in production, I would like to explore the local db (Sqlite).

Utilities such as ISETool.exe/Windows Phone Power Tools only lists developer applications..

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe add a feature to the app which allows you to back up the database to one drive

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround (I am using same idea for logs...) . But I want to know if there's any "legit" way to accomplish this simple task..